# Python Bit Shifting Negative vs positive values

Tags: python, bit-shift, negative-number

I was recently going over bit shifting and was wondering why in the below iPython output, shifting the value -1 vs shifting the value 4294967295 yielded different results?

```
In [30]: val = -1

In [31]: print "hex x %d 0x%08X" % (val, val & 0xffffffff)

hex x -1 0xFFFFFFFF

In [32]: val = val >>22

In [33]: print "hex x %d 0x%08X" % (val, val & 0xffffffff)

hex x -1 0xFFFFFFFF

In [34]: val = 4294967295

In [35]: print "hex x %d 0x%08X" % (val, val & 0xffffffff)

hex x 4294967295 0xFFFFFFFF

In [36]: val = val >>22

In [37]: print "hex x %d 0x%08X" % (val, val & 0xffffffff)

hex x 1023 0x000003FF
```

I would really appreciate any clarification, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4294967295 is 0x0...0FFFFFFFF. -1 is 0xF...FFFFFFFF. **Forever.**

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. Would you happen to know how Python is capable of replacing the shifted values with '1' in the (-1) case but '0' in the (4294967295) case?  Is this a difference behavior that is used for signed vs unsigned values?

Comment: https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4.2/file/10298f4f42dc/Objects/longobject.c#l4046

Comment: The link takes you directly to the implementation of `long.__rshift__()`.

Answer (score 2):

Short version: Because the operation is defined that way.

Long version: per the documentation, "The rules for integer representation are intended to give the most meaningful interpretation of shift and mask operations involving negative integers." In a system where numbers can be arbitrarily sized but have 2s complement representation, it follows that - at least conceptually - the sign extension carries arbitrarily far as well. So this is really the only interpretation that makes sense.

This preserves the invariant that `x >> n` <=> `int(x / (2 ** n))` across the negative numbers as well.

Comment: note: `(x >> n) == (x // 2**n)` is not equivalent to `int(x / 2**n)` e.g., `int(-22 >> 2) == -22 // 4 == -6` but `int(-22 / 4) == -5`  (`/` -- true division, `//` -- floor division).

Answer (score 1):

When a negative number is used in an expression, by the rules of two's complement arithmetic the sign bit must be extended all the way to the left bit of the expression. A right shift is preserving those left-most 1 bits. A negative number shifted right by a sufficient number of bits will always equal -1, just as a positive number shifted right by a sufficient number of bits will always equal 0.